# Another exception occurred when Checking Connection status with a try catch in urllib.error

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, traceback

I tried to make a simple code to check whether the pc has internet or not.
When the pc is connected to the internet the program runs correctly and prints "Cool, thank you for connecting me to the internet" But when I run the program without the internet an error occurs with the note: `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`.
What am I missing?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

    loop_value = 1
    while (loop_value == 1):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")
        except urllib.error as e:
            print ("Run me again, after connecting")
        else:
            print ("Cool, thank you for connecting me to internet")
            loop_value = 0
```

the error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1384, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 928, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/py/weathr.py", line 10, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/py/weathr.py", line 12, in <module>
    except urllib.error as e:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that you're trying to catch an object that isn't an exception (i.e. a class that isn't an instance of `BaseException`). Only exceptions are allowed to be caught, because only exceptions can be raised.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html) the method `urllib.request.urlopen` raises the exception `URLError` if something goes wrong, so catch that in order to react to an error.

Example implementation:

```
try:
    urllib.request.urllopen("foo.com")
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("Couldn't open foo.com. Error:")
    print(e)
```